# Jmeter Regular expression for an output

Tags: regex, performance, scripting, jmeter, beanshell

I am getting an output like

[image: Jmeter Request Response]

Plain response:

```
ticket_tax_dtls_id  tax_code    tax_amount_remitted tax_amount_p‌​roposed   tax_amount_a‌​pplicable 
667894  CN 140.0    null    140.0 
667895  US  232.0   null    232.0 
667896  YC  36.0    null    36.0 
667904  BP  56.0    null    56.0 
667905  XA 26.0 null    26.0 
667906  XF  30.0    null    30.0 
667914  AY  37.0    null    37.0 
667915  XY  46.0    null    46.0 
667916 XFHNL4.5 0.0 null    0.0
```

in Jmeter. And I need to capture the dynamic file name using regular expression extractor and capture all the variables and pass it on further in a request as below.

```
[["key0",{"taxcode":"CN","remtAmt":"90.0","propAmt":"90.0","appAmt":"90.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677839"}],["key1",{"taxcode":"XA","remtAmt":"26.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"26.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677840"}],["key2",{"taxcode":"XF","remtAmt":"90.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"90.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677841"}],["key3",{"taxcode":"XFHNL4.5","remtAmt":"0.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"0.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677842"}],["key4",{"taxcode":"AY","remtAmt":"74.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"74.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677849"}],["key5",{"taxcode":"XY","remtAmt":"46.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"46.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677850"}],["key6",{"taxcode":"XFHNL4.5","remtAmt":"0.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"0.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677851"}],["key7",{"taxcode":"US","remtAmt":"293.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"293.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677859"}],["key8",{"taxcode":"YC","remtAmt":"36.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"36.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677860"}],["key9",{"taxcode":"XFLAS4.5","remtAmt":"0.0","propAmt":"","appAmt":"0.0","apcode":"","ticketTaxId":"677861"}]]
```

I have tried making an array for each parameter but failed.

```
ticket_tax_dtls_id\n(\d+)
```

DB output is like below.

[image: DB Output]

Comment: I observed that in JSON request, you are sending old tax id values as `677839, 677840` etc. but where the response contains `667894,667895`etc. Are you replacing the JSON request tax id values with regex captured values?

Comment: Hi, This is the existing JSON request. I have not replaced with the variable coz I have not got one. Tried this ticket_tax_dtls_id(\n(\d+))+ for capturing  ticket_tax_dtls_id @Naveen

Comment: could you please post the response as plain text instead of image? so, we can try it out

Comment: ticket_tax_dtls_id tax_code tax_amount_remitted tax_amount_proposed tax_amount_applicable
667894 CN 140.0 null 140.0
667895 US 232.0 null 232.0
667896 YC 36.0 null 36.0
667904 BP 56.0 null 56.0
667905 XA 26.0 null 26.0
667906 XF 30.0 null 30.0
667914 AY 37.0 null 37.0
667915 XY 46.0 null 46.0
667916 XFHNL4.5 0.0 null 0.0
@Naveen

Answer (score 0):

the following regex worked for me:

```
(\d{6})\s+\w+
```

Use the settings shown in the screenshot to capture multiple values.

Screenshot references:

**Regex extractor:**

[image]

**View Results Tree:**

[image]

Total 9 values are captured for the given sample output in the question.

We can access each one of them later (`tax_id` is reference name), as follows:

```
first match : ${tax_id_1}
second match : ${tax_id_2}
continues..
```

Comment: Similar thing I tried using a regex as (\d{5})\s+\w+ ti capture the  output of a single column select query output giving 5 digit IDs. But this is only capturing odd place values..like 1st place,3rd place etc.. ${Var_2} is giving the value in 3rd place not 2nd.

Comment: may i know why are using 5 instead of 6? Also, please share the screenshot of ViewResultsTree (similar to the one that i attached in the answer) highlighting the captured values using regex, of Debug Sampler.

Comment: @Naveen..each ID is of 5 digit..SO I wanted to extract the 5 digits.

Comment: if first column is of 5 digit-length values, then u can use `(\d{5})\s+\w+`

Comment: @Naveen..yes this is wokring fine.Thanks